# Injury cause in elbow position

Tags: exercise, injury, injury-prevention, shoulders

I have experienced two injuries:

one doing bent over dumb bell row [like this](https://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/one-arm-dumbbell-row)

I got injured when my elbow left contact with my torso and flared up outside and got sharp pain in my shoulder.

Other one while doing chest bench press, same scenario when my elbows flaired up.

Why my shoulder is getting injured by my flaring of elbows?
I do know that flaring is wrong movement, but is there any exercise which will strengthen my shoulder muscle which is getting affected by my flaring up elbow?

Comment: why close  vote, is it duplicate or unscientific, i have seen flaring is advised against by so many